# Problems with Survey Monkey snippet to embed surveys and custom_id

Tags: surveymonkey

I tried to add the "c=XXXX" parameter to the URL defined in the snippet so that it looks like:

```
https://www.surveymonkey.com/jsEmbed.aspx?sm=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_3X_3X&c=12345
```

The survey is succesfully displayed in page (both simple version and Wordpress compatible one) and can be succesfully submitted.
Now the thing is that the `c` parameter is not ignored, is treated as a `custom_id` but is wrongly stored (or reported) when fetching answer's data via API or via Web UI; the previous example will store the answer with a custom_id value of `"12345,12345"` instead of `"12345"`

Can this be filed as a bug or I am doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with embedded surveys.  Unfortunately there is no ETA for fixing it, your best bet is to work around it.